# Check for Null in an Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have an `Expression` that looks like this:

```
obj => obj.Child.Name
```

where `Name` is a string. What I want to do is get the value of `Name`. I can get it just fine by compiling the method and invoking it, however a `NullReferenceException` is thrown if `Child` is `null`. Is there a way to check if `Child` is null in this scenario?

Comment: In C#6 there is, yes, otherwise you have to add a check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current C# version 5.0 *(or lower)*, you have to explicitly check for each property like:

```
if(obj != null && obj.Child != null)
{
  //get Name property
}
```

With C# 6.0 you will be able to check it using [Null conditional/propagation operator](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14).

```
Console.WriteLine(obj?.Child?.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
obj => obj.Child == null ? null : obj.Child.Name
```

or using C# 6

```
obj => obj.Child?.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj => obj.Child == null ? "" : obj.Child.Name;
```

Comment: This could still throw NRE if `Child` is Null

Answer (score 0):

You can filter them previously(with a **Where**), something like this:

```
var results = source.Where(obj => obj.Child != null).Select(obj => obj.Child.Name);
```

Like this, you will prevent those null reference errors.